# Hide <tr> if certain country selected

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to hide the `<tr>` with "state" unless "united states" is selected from the drop down.

```
<select name="Country"> 
<option value="" selected="selected"></option> 
<option value="United States">United States</option> 
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option> 

..........




    <tr>
        <td align=right>State:</td>
        <td align=left>
            <select id="state" name=state>
                <option value=></option>
                <option value=<?php echo $row['state']; ?> selected><?php echo $row['state']; ?></option>
                <option value=AK>AK</option>
                <option value=AL>AL</option>
                <option value=AR>AR</option>
                <option value=AZ>AZ</option>
                <option value=CA>CA</option>
```

Having a hard time figuring out the jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want

```
$('select[name="Country"]').change(function(){
   if (this.value == 'United States'){
      $('#state').closest('tr').show();
   } else {
      $('#state').closest('tr').hide();
   }
}).change();
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/XAd9h/